# InvalidTemplate. 'The number of foreach items limit exceeded for action 'Apply_to_each_3': maximum '5000' and actual '5994'.'

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow, licensing

I have the following MS flow which Search for Users >> then for each use get its info from AD:

[image]
[image]

Now the flow is working well, except that we are not getting all the users from AD. So i defined a paging for the Search for Users V2 action as follow:

[image]

But when I run the flow I got this error on the Apply to each:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is the limitation of Apply to each action for "low" [Performance profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#performance-profiles).

[image]

**Source**: [Concurrency, looping, and debatching limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#concurrency-looping-and-debatching-limits)

Comment: Also, if you are sure that number of users returned will be less than 10000, you can try splitting users array in 2 arrays with length of 5000 items & then use to apply to each action. I have not tried this yet, but you can try this approach if possible.